# Magento 2 GraphQL: Filter Products by custom attribute

Tags: products, magento2.3.3, graphql

I am using Magento 2.3.3 and GraphQL to get a list of products.

I want to query products by a custom attribute that I created in the admin.
Couldn't find in the documentation how to.

It is possible..?

Thanks!

Comment: what is your purpose? is it for layered navigation or other ?

Comment: @Mujahidh the user should be able to filter products by custom attributes such as brand, color, etc

Comment: @AlanSteiman  try this https://www.mujahidh.com/how-to-create-a-graphql-schema-for-magento-2-custom-module-with-custom-table/

Answer (score 2):

**Magento 2.4**

**Filter, sort, and get product custom attribute**

> Create Custom Attribute with below options values.

[image]

[image]

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/etc**

**schema.graphqls**

```
interface ProductInterface {
    sample_attribute: String @doc(description: "Product Custom Attribute Show")
      @resolver(
        class: "VendoreName\\ModuleName\\Model\\Resolver\\Product\\AddCustomAttribute"
      )
}

input ProductAttributeFilterInput {
  sample_attribute: FilterEqualTypeInput @doc(description: "Product Data filter with Custom Attribute Value")
}

input ProductAttributeSortInput {
  sample_attribute: SortEnum @doc(description: "Sort by the Product Custom Attribute.")
}
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Model/Resolver/Product**

**AddCustomAttribute.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\Resolver\Product;

use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Query\ResolverInterface;

/**
 * Product custom attribute field resolver
 */
class AddCustomAttribute implements ResolverInterface
{

    /**
     * @var Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory
     */
    protected $productFactory;

    /**
     * @param Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory
    ) {
        $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function resolve(
        \Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Config\Element\Field $field,
        $context,
        \Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Schema\Type\ResolveInfo $info,
        array $value = null,
        array $args = null
    ) {
        $product = $value['model'];
        $_product = $this->productFactory->create()->load($product->getId());
        return $_product->getData('sample_attribute');
    }
}
```

> **Run Magento Commands:**

```
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento in:rein
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
php bin/magento c:c
```

> **For show product custom attribute value**

```
{
  products(filter: { sku: { eq: "24-MB01" } }) {
    items {
      name
      sku
      sample_attribute
    }
  }
}
```

> **For filter product data using custom attribute**

```
{
  products(filter: { sample_attribute: { eq: "test" } }) {
    items {
      name
      sku
      sample_attribute
    }
  }
}
```

> **For sort product data using custom attribute**

```
{
  products(search: "bag", sort: {sample_attribute: DESC}) {
    items {
      name
      sku
      sample_attribute
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: $args will give NULL in the above case. Any solution would be appreciated

Comment: Yes, it's returns null, because it does not have any query param.

Comment: Why not ? For e.g products(search: "bag", sort: {sample_attribute: DESC}) , you are passing arguments right like search, sort, filter ? How to get those values in our custom resolver ?

Comment: @biplabrout You can not get that values in the custom resolver. If you want to get above mention arguments you must use this resolver vendor/magento/module-catalog-graph-ql/Model/Resolver/Products.php. Because you can check products query has already defined resolver.

Comment: Hi @msquare! Thanks but how to achieve this accessing the arguments of some other resolver class in my custom resolver ? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Okay got the solution..

1. created before plugin for products resolver
2. set the arguments values in session 
3. in my custom resolver fetch the arguments using the session

Comment: Very good @biplabrout. Nice solution. Can you please post your solution in the above post, so everyone can get it?

Comment: sure. I will add.

Answer (score 0):

Okay got the solution..

1. created before plugin for products resolver
2. set the arguments values in session
3. in my custom resolver fetch the arguments using the session